# JPA GenerationType.AUTO and setting the field manually

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity bean which has an id int field declared as **GenerationType.AUTO** so that the ID is automatically generated:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerPool implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    //setters getters
}
```

I need however to make sure the first CustomerPool that is inserted has an ID of 0.

I thought that setting a CustomerPool with the id of 0 would have had precedence over the directive instead I'm having different behaviours (using JPA over EclipseLink) but mostly the ID that I set is ignored.

So is it possible to set an ID as automatically generated if not indicated otherwise to use the specified ID if indicated?
Somehow I was used to doing that in PHP and seemed pretty natural behaviour to me.

Comment: `GenerationType.AUTO` says 'I don't care how the values are generated!' Hence you really shouldn't care, it's an implementation detail of your JPA provider and the used DBMS.  If you care you should consider other generation methods or manage the generation by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink by default validates primary keys and interprets 0 the same as Null and unset values, and so will generate a primary key value.  So you can set values as have them used, they just must be greater than 0 by default.  This is configurable through the primary key validation policy as described here:
http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_primarykey.htm

If 0 is a valid primary key, you will can set the property:

```
<property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL"/>
```